# how to live stream audio data to python server and play it

Tags: python, audio

I'm trying to live stream audio data to python server (initially I want to translate into text using google speech from the streamed audio, but seems it does not get proper audio data. that why I'm trying to play it first to check whether it gets proper audio data). for this, I'm using javascript webrtc in client side and python Aiortc on server side. then, I found that it just plays some weird noise, not proper speech when I play it on server side. and after a few second, it crashes and I got an error 
 `future: <Task finished name='Task-13' coro=<websocket_handler.<locals>.on_track.<locals>.process_audio() done, defined at ~/audio_webrtc/stream.py:52> exception=MediaStreamError()> Traceback (most recent call last): File "~/audio_webrtc/stream.py", line 55, in process_audio frame = await track.recv() File "~/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiortc/rtcrtpreceiver.py", line 206, in recv raise MediaStreamError aiortc.mediastreams.MediaStreamError`

I have no idea how to fix this error and the sound...

here is the code

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Chat</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="start">
    <input type="text" id="code-input" placeholder="Enter code..." />
    <button id="start-button" disabled>Start</button>
  </div>
  <div id="chat-room" style="display: none;">
    <button id="stop-button">Stop</button>
  </div>

  <script src="/static/client.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

client.js

```
(function () {
  "use strict";

  let code;
  let mediaStream;
  let peerConnection;
  let websocketConnection;
  let userId; // Add a variable to store the user ID

  const MESSAGE_TYPE = {
    SDP: 'SDP',
    CANDIDATE: 'CANDIDATE',
  };

  document.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
    if (event.target.id === 'code-input') {
      const { value } = event.target;
      if (value.length > 8) {
        document.getElementById('start-button').disabled = false;
        code = value;
      } else {
        document.getElementById('start-button').disabled = true;
        code = null;
      }
    }
  });

  document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    if (event.target.id === 'start-button' && code) {
      startChat();
    }
    if (event.target.id === 'stop-button') {
      stopChat();
    }
  });

  const startChat = async () => {
    try {
      mediaStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false });
      console.log('Media stream:', mediaStream); // Check the media stream object

      showChatRoom();

      peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection({
        iceServers: [{ urls: 'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302' }],
      });

      peerConnection.onnegotiationneeded = async () => {
        await createAndSendOffer();
      };

      peerConnection.onicecandidate = (iceEvent) => {
        if (iceEvent && iceEvent.candidate) {
          sendMessage({
            message_type: MESSAGE_TYPE.CANDIDATE,
            content: iceEvent.candidate,
          });
        }
      };

      mediaStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => peerConnection.addTrack(track, mediaStream));

      console.log('Peer connection:', peerConnection); // Check the peer connection object
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  const stopChat = () => {
    if (mediaStream) {
      mediaStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
    }
    if (peerConnection) {
      peerConnection.close();
    }
    showStartButton();
  };

  const showChatRoom = () => {
    document.getElementById('start').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('chat-room').style.display = 'block';
  };

  const showStartButton = () => {
    document.getElementById('start').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('chat-room').style.display = 'none';
  };

  const createAndSendOffer = async () => {
    try {
      const offer = await peerConnection.createOffer();
      await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
      sendMessage({
        message_type: MESSAGE_TYPE.SDP,
        content: peerConnection.localDescription,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  const sendMessage = (message) => {
    if (code) {
      websocketConnection.send(JSON.stringify({
        ...message,
        code,
        id: userId, // Include the user ID in the message
      }));
      console.log('Sent message:', message); // Check the sent message
    }
  };

  // Connect to WebSocket server
  websocketConnection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/ws'); // URL pointing to Python server
  websocketConnection.onopen = () => {
    console.log('WebSocket connection opened');
  };
  websocketConnection.onclose = () => {
    console.log('WebSocket connection closed');
  };
  websocketConnection.onmessage = (event) => {
    const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
    const { message_type, content, id } = data;
    userId = id; // Store the user ID
    console.log('Received message:', data); // Check the received message

    if (message_type === MESSAGE_TYPE.CANDIDATE && content) {
      handleCandidate(content);
    } else if (message_type === MESSAGE_TYPE.SDP) {
      if (content.type === 'offer') {
        handleOffer(content);
      } else if (content.type === 'answer') {
        handleAnswer(content);
      }
    }
  };
  websocketConnection.onerror = (error) => {
    console.error(`WebSocket error: ${error}`);
  };

  const handleCandidate = async (candidate) => {
    try {
      await peerConnection.addIceCandidate(candidate);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  const handleOffer = async (offer) => {
    try {
      await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(offer);
      const answer = await peerConnection.createAnswer();
      await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);
      sendMessage({
        message_type: MESSAGE_TYPE.SDP,
        content: peerConnection.localDescription,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  const handleAnswer = async (answer) => {
    try {
      await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(answer);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };
})();
```

and the server.py

```
import pyaudio
import asyncio
import numpy as np
from aiortc import RTCPeerConnection, RTCSessionDescription, RTCIceCandidate
from aiortc.sdp import candidate_from_sdp
from aiohttp import web, WSMsgType
import json
import uuid
from pathlib import Path
routes = web.RouteTableDef()

peer_connections = {}  # dictionary to store RTCPeerConnection instances

# Audio parameters
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 16000

# Create PyAudio instance
audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()

# Create a stream for audio playback
stream = audio.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                    channels=CHANNELS,
                    rate=RATE,
                    output=True)

@routes.get('/ws')
async def websocket_handler(request):
    ws = web.WebSocketResponse()
    await ws.prepare(request)
    pc_id = None  # this will store the PeerConnection ID

    async for msg in ws:
        if msg.type == WSMsgType.TEXT:
            data = json.loads(msg.data)
            message_type = data.get("message_type")
            content = data.get("content")
            pc_id = data.get("id")

            pc = peer_connections.get(pc_id)
            if pc is None:
                # create a new PeerConnection if it does not exist
                pc = RTCPeerConnection()
                peer_connections[pc_id] = pc

                @pc.on("track")
                def on_track(track):
                    if track.kind == "audio":
                        print("Track %s received" % track.kind)

                        async def process_audio():
                            while True:
                                #try:
                                    frame = await track.recv()
                                    pcm_data = frame.to_ndarray().tobytes()
                                    stream.write(pcm_data)
                                #except Exception as e:
                                    #print("Error processing audio:", str(e))
                                    #break

                        asyncio.ensure_future(process_audio())
                    else:
                        print("Ignoring track of kind:", track.kind)

            if message_type == "SDP":
                sdp = RTCSessionDescription(**content)
                await pc.setRemoteDescription(sdp)
                answer = await pc.createAnswer()
                await pc.setLocalDescription(answer)
                await ws.send_json({
                    "message_type": "SDP",
                    "content": {
                        "type": "answer",
                        "sdp": pc.localDescription.sdp
                    },
                })
            elif message_type == "CANDIDATE":
                candidate_sdp = content['candidate']
                candidate_obj = candidate_from_sdp(candidate_sdp)
                candidate_obj.sdpMid = content['sdpMid']
                candidate_obj.sdpMLineIndex = content['sdpMLineIndex']
                candidate = RTCIceCandidate(**candidate_obj.__dict__)
                await pc.addIceCandidate(candidate)

        elif msg.type == WSMsgType.CLOSE:
            pc = peer_connections.get(pc_id)
            if pc:
                await pc.close()
            break

    return ws


app = web.Application()
app.router.add_routes(routes)
app.router.add_static('/static/', path=str(Path(__file__).parent / 'static'), name='static')
web.run_app(app)
```

so, when I run the server, and go to `http://localhost:8080/static/index.html`, and then type the any code more than 9 letter, it will start the microphone audio stream.
client.js will stream the audio to server and `process_audio` in the server will play the stream. but, I only can hear noise, not speech, and it will crash in a few second. I really don't know how to fix this problem...